# tensorflow GradientTape returns None although there is a gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using `GradientTape` to calculate derivatives for probability distributions. Here is a simple example with a multivariate normal:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

with tf.GradientTape() as g:

    mu = tf.Variable(np.ones((2)))
    sigma = tf.Variable(np.eye(2))

    dist = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(
    loc=mu,
    covariance_matrix=sigma)

    num_samples = 10
    samples = dist.sample((num_samples,))
    logprobs = dist.log_prob(samples)

g.jacobian(logprobs, mu) # this does not work as expected
```

This does not work as expected. The gradient computed by `g.jacobian` is `None`, which is not true. Of course the probability depends on the mean of the distribution.

I suspect that the backwards pass may flow into the generation of the samples, which also depends on mu. Maybe this can't be calculated properly. In fact the following addition fixes the problem:

```py
samples = dist.sample((num_samples,))
samples = tf.stop_gradient(samples) # this line is new
# ...
g.jacobian(logprobs, mu) # now works
```

Is it possible to set up some kind of error reporting with `GradientTape`? There are more complicated examples where I am checking gradients to see if variables depend on each other. If `None` does not reliably mean `None`, it could be a problem.